# Изменить значение атрибута

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть вот такой код:

```
<div class="owl-item active">

 ...

 <div class="amasty-label-container amasty-label-container-2-2094" style="opacity: 0;width: 98px;line-height: normal;height: 40px;position: absolute;z-index: 995;top: 0px;left: 0px;">Some Text</div>

 ...

</div>
```

Нужно используя JS заменить `opacity: 0` на `opacity: 1` для всех элементов, которые относятся к `.owl-item.active`

Comment: это не код, а html разметка и не понятно каким образом она относиться к `.owl-item.active`

Comment: Самым прямым образом, если вставить весь фрагмент кода (html-разметки), вряд ли это будет читабельно. Тогда не "кодер", "html-разметчик". Сомневаюсь, что назвав html разметку кодом, человек допустил грубую ошибку. Ой, простите можно же назвать html-верстальщик

Comment: ну так после того как отредактировали вопрос - понятнее стало с `.owl-item`

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko, осталось только определится, что к разметке тоже применяется выражение "код", хоть и используется реже. Поэтому утверждение "это не код" не корректно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.owl-item.active > *').css('opacity', 1);
```